# How to print only specific characters recognized from a string with LEX

Tags: regex, lex

Hi I am studying about LEX. When the phrase corresponding to the regular expression is in a specific string, it is output as it is. Is there a way to output only the part corresponding to the regular expression?

For example I wrote a regular expression that recognizes **nice**.
And when string **nice to meet you** is input, if there is nice, I want to output nice as it is.
But now, when I run the code I wrote, the whole input is executed together, not a specific word. Any way?

code:

```
%%
nice printf("%s","target");
```

input.txt:

```
nice to meet you
```

output:

```
target to meet you
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you need to ask is what flex does with the parts of the input not matched by any pattern you provide. And the answer is that it uses its [default rule](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html#Matching), which matches any single character *and echoes it to standard output*.

So if you don't want that to happen, you have to make sure that you match everything and explicitly ignore what you don't want to do anything else to.

You can use a fallback rule like this (at the end of your rules):

```
.|\n      /* Do nothing */
```

Comment: Thank you so much~ No matter how hard I tried, I finally solved it